# Issue changing a QPushButton style in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I have created a QPushButton in Qt without applying any style, so it inherits the style from Windows10, with this result:

[image: Windows Style]

Then I wanted to change temporary the color of the button, so I used:

```
pushButton->setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255,220,220)")
```

getting this result:

[image: Red Style]

Already this result does not satisfy me because also the style is slightly different from the original one. Anyway the next step was that the button had to return to the "normal" style when pressed, so I added this command

```
pushButton->setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(240,240,240)")
```

but the result is different from the starting button:

[image]

Can you please give me some advice to better manage the style?

Thanks

Comment: What happens if you set empty `QString` to the button's stylesheet to revert to the normal style instead?

Comment: It works fine, at least the button reverts to the original style! Thanks. And any advice to change the background color to pink like I have done but keeping the original style?

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not aware of a good way to do that. You can try to tinker more with the stylesheet, for example, try different `border-style` values, some might look just like Windows 10 style. See [this](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-a-qpushbutton-using-the-box-model) for more details on how you can change the appearance of `QPushButton` using stylesheets.

Answer (score 1):

Actually when you set `background-color` alone to `QPushButton`, The background may not appear unless you set some value for border.

Look here for (List of Stylable Widgets: QPushButton)
http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html

I think in windows 10 for some reason, you are able to see something without even setting border.

But the recommended way is to set some border value.

So try setting border value as said below, and see if it addresses your requirement:

```
pushButton->setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255,220,220);border: none; ")
```

In the above said link you can find below information:

***Warning: If you only set a background-color on a QPushButton, the background may not appear unless you set the border property to some value. This is because, by default, the QPushButton draws a native border which completely overlaps the background-color.***

Answer (score 0):

Here are some snippets you may find quite similar and helpful.

I had an *Update* button which I turned into red *Cancel* button. Once the update action is finished or cancel is pressed, I restored the original color and text.

```
// Global variables to save off button state
QPalette update_btn_palette_restore;
QString update_btn_text_restore;
```

....

```
// Update button is pressed. 
// Save the palette and text.
update_btn_palette_restore = _ui->update_button->palette ();
update_btn_text_restore = _ui->update_button->text ();

// Change the color palette and text
QPalette p=palette();
p.setBrush(QPalette::Button,Qt::red);
_ui->update_button->setPalette(p);
_ui->update_button->setText ("Cancel");
```

....

```
// Handler for when either cancel is pressed or update has finished
if(! update_btn_text_restore.isEmpty ()) {
    _ui->update_button->setText (update_btn_text_restore);
    _ui->update_button->setPalette(update_btn_palette_restore);
}
```